# How to check multiple checkboxes without a fixed value in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, ide

I would like to check multiple checkboxes (with Selenium IDE), they have no fixed value, but they all contain the text "abc".
It is unknown how many checkboxes there are.
So I want to check all the checkboxes that contain the text "abc".
Who can help me?

Comment: Can i tell u programmatically..?

Comment: Can you give that all checkbox element?

Comment: Can you share the HTML for that page?

Comment: I started with a script, this way I program my test: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FAmMM.png

Comment: Hi Heelen, Also require your HTML code portion.

Comment: <tbody>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//tr[contains(td[2],&quot;abc&quot;)]/td/input</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>store</td>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>regelnr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>storeElementPresent</td>
 <td>//tr[${regelnr}]/td/input</td>
 <td>VarSelecterenTF</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>while</td>
 <td>${VarSelecterenTF} </td>
 <td>true</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//tr[contains(td[2],&quot;abc&quot;)]/td/input</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>store</td>
 <td>${regelnr} + 1</td>
 <td>regelnr</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>endWhile</td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution, see the picture: 
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiSvR.png)